# How do I solve for t, where $t$ is both the input to a sine function and the result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem specifically, here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. $0 = 3^{1/2} \times (1/2) \times t^{-1/2} - 2\sin(t)$
2. $0 = \dfrac{3^{1/2}}{(2 \times t^{1/2})}- 2\sin(t)$
3. $2\sin(t) = \dfrac{3^{1/2}}{2 \times t^{1/2}}$
4. $\sin(t) = \dfrac{3^{1/2}}{4 \times t^{1/2}}$

But now I can't take the inverse because the t is still on the right-hand side.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working in degrees or radians?

Comment: This can only be numerically solved afaik

Comment: @FShrike. We can have (not too bad) approximations

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Remember that the simpler equation $x=\cos(x)$ does not show analytical solution. So, only numerical methods or approximations will do the job.

Cross multiply by $\sqrt t$ and consider that you look for the zeros (there is an infinite number of them) of function
$$f(t)=\sqrt{t} \sin (t)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$$ The first root is simple to approximate
$$\sin(t) \sim t \implies t^{\frac 32}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\implies t_1\sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}=0.573$$ while the exact solution is $t_1=0.596$.

Now, just graphing, you can notice that the other roots $t_n$ are "close" to $(n-1)\pi$. So, make a series expansion around this value and use [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

To give you an idea, using a very limited expansion would give $t_2=2.88779$ while the "exact" solution, as given by Newton method, is $2.88376$ and it will be better and better for larger $n$.